# Access Http.context in a mixed Scala/Java Play! application

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a mixed Scala/Java Play! application (version 2.5.11). I just moved the WebSocket handling from Java to Scala but the controller receiving the request and returning the response is still in Java. Now I can't access cookies anymore (nor any Http.context)

In more detail:

- The Java controller receives the request for a WebSocket and calls the Scala service.
- The Scala service produces a `play.api.mvc.WebSocket` that is then given to the Java controller which more or less just gives it to the client.
- Usually WebSockets in Java are of type `play.mvc.WebSocket`.
- Somehow if I use the Scala WebSocket Play! doesn't give me the `Http.context`:  If I call `Http.Context.current().request().cookies()` I just get a
  `java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.`

Does anyone know how I can access `Http.Context` in an controller action that returns a `play.api.mvc.WebSocket` in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying to the java Http.Context class, have you considered just to use the request object that you can pass to the controller method?

The controller method will look like this:

```
  def socket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[String, String] { request =>
    // headers
    val headers = request.headers
    // cookies
    val cookies = request.cookies
    // your websocket process
    //  ...
  }
```

Comment: This is not a possibility since my controller is in Java and there I can only access the request object via Http.Context and this doesn't work because the returned WebSocket is a Scala one. :(